# Is Strong Consistency Possible In MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

When I search the internet, I found different ideas about consistency in MongoDB. For example, this blog (https://www.instaclustr.com/blog/cassandra-vs-mongodb/) says "MongoDB remains strongly consistent only as long as all reads are directed to the primary member."

But when I check MongoDB official documents, I couldn’t find an info like that. But I saw a thing like causal consistency (https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/what-is-causal-consistency-in-mongodb/172041)

So I'm confused. Is there any suggestion or comment?

Comment: If I had to choose between a random opinion in the internets and the vendor, I'd put more trust in the latter. Out curiosity, what are the usecases where causal consistency is not enough?